# Wiremock and Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-test, spring-restcontroller, wiremock

I have a flow in Spring integration, which works as follows

Read from MQ--> Do a Message Transformation-->Send the transformed message to an Api

Now in my integration test, I am trying to mock the Api out and I tried 2 flavours but did not succeed.

Here is the test with **Wiremock flavour** (also posted on [Wiremock Github](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/653))

```
String requestBody = TestUtil.createSampleInputMessage(rNumber);

System.out.println("Expected Post msg by EvApiClient :" + requestBody);


stubFor(post(urlEqualTo(TestUtil.EVENT_URL))
            //.withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
            //.withRequestBody(equalToJson(requestBody))

        );


ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9966/__admin", String.class);

System.out.println("Printing Expected response :" + response);

sendToJmsOutChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(TestUtil.createSampleInputMessage(receiptNumber)).build());

verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(TestUtil.EVENT_URL)));`
```

The failure I get is

> com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: A request was unmatched by any stub mapping. Closest stub mapping was: expected:<
>   POST
>   /pa/his/v1/ev> but was:<
>   POST
>   /pa/his/v1/ev>

Here is the test with **Spring's MockRestServiceServer**

```
@Before
public void setup() throws PdsListenerException, URISyntaxException {       

    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

}

@Test
public void test_001_success() throws InterruptedException, JSONException, URISyntaxException {
    rNumber = TestUtil.generateRNumber();

    String requestBody = TestUtil.createSampleInputMessage(rNumber);



    mockServer.expect(once(), requestTo("http://localhost:9966" + TestUtil.EVENT_URL))
        .andRespond(withCreatedEntity(new URI(TestUtil.EVENT_URL)));



    sendToJmsOutChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(TestUtil.createSampleInputMessage(rNumber)).build());


    mockServer.verify();


}
```

The failure I get is

> java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s).
>   0 request(s) executed.

I am not sure why the matching is failing. Is there anyone that can point out where I should be looking at.

Comment: Maybe that must be `restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9966" + TestUtil.EVENT_URL)` ?

Comment: I actually added this for debugging purposes...removed it still no luck

Comment: Ok. Would you mind sharing the entire test to play from our side. I'm not familiar with Wiremock, but at least I can run test locally to figure out what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the help mate...I found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found out what the problem was with WireMock, and I will be using this flavour.

What I needed to change is

```
    @ClassRule
public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(9966);

@Rule
public WireMockClassRule instanceRule = wireMockRule;

...

instanceRule.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo(Constants.EVENT_URL))

...
 instanceRule.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(TestUtil.EVENT_URL)));
```

Basically use the instance of the WireMockRule for stubbing and verifying, and not as I was doing before.

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo(TestUtil.EVENT_URL))
```